# adapter = new ListLeaderBoardAdapter(this, mLeaderboardlist);

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

[what shall i do to this one?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NjUT.png)

[This is my list adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiEhP.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Separately: Post code and error messages **as text**, not as images. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Change `this` to `this.getContext()`

Comment: sir thankyou very much ... sorry for my improper posting behavior ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call this from fragment. replace this with getActivity().

change your code like this

```
adapter = new ListLeaderBoardAdapter(getActivity(), mLeaderboardlist);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this make

```
adapter = new ListLeaderBoradAdapter(getActivity(),yourArraylist);
```